What would you recommend to fix this problem with outdoor aluminum trim flecking paint?
I am having paint fleck off aluminum trim on my house.  What would be a recommendation to correct this problem?  If painting it, how long would it last?

Pictures of the problem trim would be helpful for us to diagnose what to do.


Strip the existing paint.
Get a good quality metal primer and apply properly (i.e. - follow the instructions on the tin).
Paint with a quality paint.

It will last until it fails again.
